# Why after I build php with --with-pdo-mysql=shared,mysqlnd, I can not find PDO module when I run "php -m"?

Tags: php, linux, pdo, lamp

when I run php -r "phpinfo();", I can get the following message about PDO thing:

```
Configure
Command
=>
'./configure'
...
'--with-pdo-odbc=shared,unixODBC,/usr'
'--with-pdo-mysql=shared,mysqlnd'
'--with-pdo-pgsql=shared,/usr'
'--with-pdo-sqlite=shared,/usr'
'--with-pdo-dblib=shared,/usr'
...
```

but when I run `"php -m"`, I can not find pdo any more, could any one tells me what wrong with it ?

Comment: Is it really absolutely necessary for you to be building it by hand?  Most linux distributions have a package manager (rpm, apt, yum, etc) that can manage all the dependencies and automatically install dependant packages as well.

Comment: You have built the extensions as shared modules, which isn't recommended in general, and means you will need to enable each of them with a `extension=/path/to/pdo_xxx.so` line in php.ini.

Comment: I just wanna build it by hand once, I think it's fun, :)

Comment: weird idea of fun, but fair enough :)